# Can I safely use 'nonatomic' ivars within a dispatch_barrier of a customized concurrent queue?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, swift, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

Is it safe to access non-atomic ivars from within a dispatch_barrier of a customized-concurrent queue?

The following code snippet is an abridged version of method using a dispatch barrier:

```
- (void)cacheData:(NSData *)data toFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    dispatch_barrier_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
        [_memoryCache setObject:data forKey:fileName];
        // ...
        }
    });
}
```

I want to get a basic understanding of the non-atomic thread safety (i.e., without the overhead of using atomic vs non-atomic iVars).

This concerns Swift as will as Objective-C.

Comment: All ivars are `nonatomic`. It's properties that can be set as `atomic` or `nonatomic`. And it's probably not the use of the ivar you need to worry about. It's more likely a need of worry about whether the methods on the referenced object are thread-safe.

Comment: All I want to know is, is it thread-safe to use non-atomic ivars within a dispatch-barrier paradigm?  ...begin that only one thread can access ivars, etc. at a time and hence, no thread collision.

Answer (score 4):

## Atomic ≠ Thread safe

In order to answer this, let's first split the read/write operations into 3 distinct categories:

- **Direct Writes:** When you directly set a variable/property to a given value. For example:

```
yourDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

- **Indirect Writes:** When you *mutate* the object itself by changing a variable on it. For example:

```
[yourDictionary setObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
```

- **Reads:** When you do any form of passive reading from an object (when the reading doesn't lead to any changes to the object itself). For example:

```
NSString* foo = [yourDictionary objectForKey:@"bar"];
```

---

### So what does the `atomic` attribute on properties (you cannot set this on an ivar directly) ensure?

It ensures that **direct writes** and **reads** are serialised. However, it does *nothing* to protect the object from being indirectly written to while being read from another thread, **which is unsafe**.

Therefore, `atomic` properties make the most amount of sense with **immutable** objects (such as `NSString`, `NSDictionary` & `NSArray`). Once these objects are set, you cannot mutate them, and therefore are thread safe when `atomic`.

[See here for full a list of the thread safe immutable objects.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html)

**If you want to use the `atomic` attribute on a mutable object, you will have *still* to ensure yourself that indirect writes and reads are serialised correctly.**

---

### What does the `nonatomic` attribute ensure?

**Nothing.**

No serialisation will take place for direct writes, indirect writes and reads. As a consequence, it is faster. However it is completely up to **you** to ensure that reads and writes are serialised correctly.

---

### So how do I serialise read and writes?

You are indeed correct in approaching this by using a concurrent GCD queue. [GCD queues don't impose some of the costs that traditional locks bring with them.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1)

So, if you're looking to do this on a `nonatomic` ivar, you'll need to serialise the **direct writes**, **indirect writes** and **reads**. If you were doing this on an `atomic` property, you'd only need to serialise the **indirect writes** and **reads**.

As you have in your question, you should use a `dispatch_barrier` on your concurrent queue in order to make any **writes** (direct or indirect).

This is because a `dispatch_barrier` will wait until all tasks on the concurrent queue have been completed before preceding, and will block any further tasks from taking place until it has completed. **Therefore the writes will take place without any interruptions from other writes or reads, while multiple reads can take place concurrently**

You should therefore also channel any reads of the object through your concurrent queue as well, using a `dispatch_sync`. You shouldn't have to use a barrier for your reads, as multiple reads from different threads shouldn't cause a problem.

I hope this clarifies the issue for you.

---

### TL;DR

Yes, your approach appears to be correct.

Comment: What I'm curious about, is that an iVar need not be atomic within the dispatch-barrier paradigm and hence, one can avoid the overhead of atomic iVars.  That is, it's okay to use nonatomic ivars within a dispatch_barrier paradigm.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. As long all your writes take place within a `dispatch_barrier` and all your reads also take place on the concurrent queue, you will be fine. I have updated my answer to hopefully make things clearer.

Comment: The reason for my query is the fact that the atomic/@synchronized pattern has real costs.  I've read that atomic accessors can average over twenty times (20x) slower than nonatomic accessors.  Thus, I would think it's prudent to use the GCD paradigm with non-atomic accessors for greater efficiency.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee well the `atomic` vs `nonatomic` argument is fairly trivial in your case, because you're going to have to use GCD to synchronise your reading and writing *anyway*, as you're working with mutable objects. So, as you're already implementing your own synchronisation system, using an `atomic` property is redundant anyway. So, yes you want to be using `nonatomic` & GCD.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee and yes, sorry I kinda missed your point there, GCD is generally more efficient than traditional locks/@synchronised.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee did this help you? be sure to accept if it did :)

Comment: I wanted to confirm my knowledge.   An interviewer and I discussed @synchronized & atomic.  I argued that GCD was the paradigm to follow.  The troglodyte apparently didn't understand my argument for GCD vs @synchronized/atomic paradigm; nor believed that I understood the concept of a 'thread-safe' management.  She critique that I didn't know anything... didn't get the job.  ... I got pissed.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee wow, I've never heard of that either being an interview question, or anyone blindly advocating for an atomic/@synchronized approach. While the atomic/@synchronized approach is dead simple to set up, it brings lots of overhead with it (such as automatic error handling, which you shouldn't need with good code). It also will force you to serially read a property, meaning you can't take advantage of multiple concurrent reads (which is perfectly safe in most cases). GCD is much better on performance. I honestly don't think I'd want to work at such a place!

Comment: Regarding Indirect Writes, suppose I have a custom NSObject class Foo, which has a property named bar, setting its property foo.bar = "newValue" like this is also indirect writes? GCD is much better on performance, but do I need more custom concurrent queues to be dispatched with updating task?